# Batch Script pauses while running

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written a batch script which is as follows:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set "outfile=wmic-full-output.txt"

    for /L %%y in (73,1,79) do (
    for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (

    echo ********************************************************* >> "!outfile!"

    set "node=172.22.%%y.%%z"

    echo !node! >> "!outfile!"

    ping -n 1 -l 1 -w 1 !node! | find "Packets" >> "!outfile!"
    if not errorlevel 1 (
    nbtstat -A !node! >> !outfile!
    nbtstat -A !node! | find /i "Host not found." >nul 2>&1 && ( echo Not a Windows Machine >> !outfile! ) || (

    for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"!node!" computersystem get domain^,manufacturer^,model^,name^,systemtype^,username^,wakeuptype /format:csv ^| find /i "!node!"'
    ) do (
        set "_domain=%%a"
    set "_manufacturer=%%b"
        set "_model=%%c"
        set "_name=%%d"
        set "_systemType=%%e"
        set "_userName=%%f"
    for %%j in (!_username!) do (set "_username=%%j")
    if "!_username!"=="6" (set "_username=Not Available")
     )


    for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"!node!" bios get serialNumber^,version /format:csv ^| find /i "!node!"'
    ) do (
        set "_serialNumber=%%a"
    )

    for /f "tokens=2-3 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"!node!" os get name^,totalvisiblememorysize^,version /format:csv ^| find /i "!node!"'
    ) do (
        set "_osName=%%a"
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=|" %%j in ("!_osName!") do (set "_osName=%%j")
    set "_memory=%%b"
    )

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"!node!" cpu get name^,version /format:csv ^| find /i "!node!"'
    ) do (
        set "_cpu=%%a"

    echo HostName= !_name! >> "!outfile!"
    echo Domain= !_domain!>> "!outfile!"
    echo UserName= !_userName! >> "!outfile!"
    echo Manufacturer= !_manufacturer! >> "!outfile!"
    echo Model= !_model! >> "!outfile!"
    echo SystemType= !_systemType! >> "!outfile!"
    echo SerialNumber= !_serialNumber! >> "!outfile!"
    echo OperatingSystem= !_osName! >> "!outfile!"
    echo RAM= !_memory! >> "!outfile!"
    echo Processor= !_cpu! >> "!outfile!"

    )
  ))
))
```

When above script is executed on a Windows server, after successfully executing up to 172.22.73.12, it pauses permanently. When the `outfile` contents are observed, latest result recorded is the output of `nbtstat -A 172.22.73.13`.

Is anything wrong with the script?

Comment: Without studying your entire script - start it from 172.22.73.11 and see if it pauses and report back.

Comment: I did the changes and executed the script again. Results upto 172.22.73.13 were recorded in `wmic-full-output.txt`, and for 172.22.73.14 onwards, results were dumped to a new file `!outfile!` with the line of *s and `!node!` printed on alternate lines.

Comment: Execute the appropriate commands manually at the cmd prompt for machines on the 13 and 14 octets.  Something would appear to change.

Comment: They get executed successfully, individually. But, fail to run in the script.

Comment: Something about the output is different, which your batch script is testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set "outfile=wmic-full-output.txt"

    for /L %%y in (73,1,79) do (
    for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (

    echo ********************************************************* >> "!outfile!"

    set "node=172.22.%%y.%%z"

    echo !node! >> "!outfile!"

    ping -n 1 -l 1 -w 1 !node! | find /i "TTL=" >> "!outfile!"
    if not errorlevel 1 (
    nbtstat -A !node! >> !outfile!
    nbtstat -A !node! | find /i "Host not found." >nul 
    if errorlevel 1 (


    for /f "tokens=2-7 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"!node!" computersystem get domain^,manufacturer^,model^,name^,systemtype^,username^,wakeuptype /format:csv ^| find /i "!node!"'
    ) do (
        set "_domain=%%a"
    set "_manufacturer=%%b"
        set "_model=%%c"
        set "_name=%%d"
        set "_systemType=%%e"
        set "_userName=%%f"
    for %%j in (!_username!) do (set "_username=%%j")
    if "!_username!"=="6" (set "_username=Not Available")
     )


    for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"!node!" bios get serialNumber^,version /format:csv ^| find /i "!node!"'
    ) do (
        set "_serialNumber=%%a"
    )

    for /f "tokens=2-3 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"!node!" os get name^,totalvisiblememorysize^,version /format:csv ^| find /i "!node!"'
    ) do (
        set "_osName=%%a"
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=|" %%j in ("!_osName!") do (set "_osName=%%j")
    set "_memory=%%b"
    )

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in (
        'wmic /node:"!node!" cpu get name^,version /format:csv ^| find /i "!node!"'
    ) do (
        set "_cpu=%%a"

    echo HostName= !_name! >> "!outfile!"
    echo Domain= !_domain!>> "!outfile!"
    echo UserName= !_userName! >> "!outfile!"
    echo Manufacturer= !_manufacturer! >> "!outfile!"
    echo Model= !_model! >> "!outfile!"
    echo SystemType= !_systemType! >> "!outfile!"
    echo SerialNumber= !_serialNumber! >> "!outfile!"
    echo OperatingSystem= !_osName! >> "!outfile!"
    echo RAM= !_memory! >> "!outfile!"
    echo Processor= !_cpu! >> "!outfile!"

    )

)
)
)
)
echo done
pause
```

Comment: Success !! Everything is working fine now. Thank you foxidrive for your efforts. You have been working on this since yesterday.

Comment: I'm glad it works - some of the results were conflicting but we got there.  One thing to be aware of is that the test for a Windows machine will fail in some cases because I found on my machine I get the message `Host not found.` from `nbtstat` because I have VirtualBox installed.

Comment: In that case, can we use `nbtstat -A !node! | find /i "MAC Address" > nul` along with `if not errorlevel 1`, so that we can get results only for physical nodes and not virtual machines?

Comment: I get a bogus mac address when I use nbtstat -A on my router. `MAC Address = 00-00-00-00-00-00`  Do your Linux and Apple machines return that same bogus mac address?  My Windows machine returns a valid mac address.

Comment: No. When I run `nbtstat -A` for any other machine than Windows (not tried for switches and routers), it would definitely return `Host not found.`

Comment: The problem is that a Windows machine can also return `Host not found.`  It seems that linux/mac/windows machines all return `MAC Address` too.

Comment: I have checked that on multiple Linux physical nodes, it is not showing `MAC Address` in the result. As of now, I am happy with the way the script is performing. If any issue is experienced, I will surely share it with you.